# fb comments - cannot see the full widget anymore

Tags: facebook, widget, comments, size

Since yesterday, I cannot see the full widget for comments from facebook. I have a website with articles, and for every article, a fb comments widget. First, I've thought it was a problem of layers or something, but i've created a new file and same problem is happening.
The code is:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=386320764714835";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://steagu.ro/index.php?id=2806&amp;cat=1" data-num-posts="5" data-width="630"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see it in action [here](http://steagu.ro/testfb.php).
I've test it on Firefox 16.0.1 and also in IE 9.0.7

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include this line :

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

Use this Code and check

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=386320764714835";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://steagu.ro/index.php?id=2806&amp;cat=1" data-num-posts="25" data-width="630"></div>

</body>
</html>
```